# How to use local packages in Laravel Sail

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-sail

I'm building at the moment a new Laravel Package on my local machine.
I also have a local project with Laravel Sail to test the new package.

** Laravel Sail composer.json **

```
"repositories": {
        "local": {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../packages/new-package"
        }
    }
```

Now when I try the command `sail composer require vendor/new-package`, I get the error: `The url supplied for the path (../packages/new-package) repository does not exist`.

I know my Sail App is in a Docker container and the path `../packages/new-package` can not exist there. But how can I fix this, how can I use a local packge in a Laravel Sail Application?

Comment: I think the easy think to do is [publish](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#sail-customization) the docker-compse file sail uses and then add a [path mapping](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes) to where the local packages would be so they are also mounted on the container

Comment: @apokryfos thanks for the quick answer! Can i ask you how you would do the path mapping?

Comment: probably something like `"- ../packages:/var/www/packages"` (this would be under your `volumes` array. `var/www` here is the parent directory of your app root (that's usually where it is) but yours may differ

Comment: @apokryfos You're my hero!

Comment: @apokryfos consider adding that as an answer, that was exactly what I needed too!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when using Sail only the project directory is mounted in the Sail container as a volume.

You can [customise](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail#sail-customization) your sail compose file by running:

```
sail artisan sail:publish
```

This should publish the default Sail `docker-compose.yml` file in the project root directory to allow you to modify it.

In order to allow composer to load packages from local path repositories you can mount the path in the exact same relative location in the container. This may look like something like below:

```yaml
volumes:
  # Default one
  - '.:/var/www/html'
  # New one
  - ../packages:/var/www/packages
```